# Создать таблицу и поле в ней если неизвестно их существование

Tags: postgresql

Коллеги, представим себе, что мне надо создать таблицу `table` с полем `field`. Но в момент создания мы не знаем, существует ли такая таблица и, более того, если таблица и существует, то мы не знаем, существует ли в ней поле. То есть, возможны три варианта:

1. Таблицы нет
2. Таблица есть, но поля нет
3. Есть и таблица и поле

Вариант, который я использую, в общем меня устраивает и состоит из двух запросов. Первым делом создаем таблицу, если ее нет:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (field INTEGER);
```

Теперь у нас гарантировано существует таблица, но не факт, что с полем, поэтому создаем поле, если его нет:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS field INTEGER;
```

Повторю, вариант вполне устраивает, но хочется совершенства. Может быть есть варианты, чтобы в один запрос?

Comment: *вариант вполне устраивает, но хочется совершенства.* Свалить принципиально различные операции в одну кучу - вот ни разу не совершенство. Скорее наоборот. *Может быть есть варианты, чтобы в один запрос?* Не завезли...

Comment: @Akina то есть, резюме: вариант, который я использую приемлемый и искать альтернативу ни к чему? Правильно?

Comment: Ну как бы порядок действий-то логичный... хотя я бы не полагался на удачу, а запросил системные таблицы на предмет наличия как таблицы, так и поля в ней, и в зависимости от результата выполнял тот или иной запрос. Формально-то можно напороться на ситуацию, когда таблица есть, но не своя, и запихивание в него своего поля может запросто поломать чужой процесс.. или упереться в отсутствие прав на изменение структуры, с соответствующей ошибкой.

Comment: @Akina понял, благодарю за совет!